# How can I reference my array of markers using setState?

Tags: react-native, syntax-error, setstate

I have some old code that used to run but now I receive a warning. When fixing it using setState, I get a simple syntax error. Obviously I am misunderstanding something but not sure what. I have provided a snack example [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/map-index-reference) that reproduces my error exactly.

> calling setState causes error - Do not mutate state directly

I also included my original line below. It used to work fine.

From looking at a similar question I tried using just this.state.markers which gives the same error.

I appreciate any and all insight more than you know.

```
 ref={ref => this.state.markers[index] = ref}
```

Comment: Just WTH is this line: `ref={ref => this.setState({marker[index]}) = ref}`. This line alone has multiple errors. What do you think this line does anyway?

Comment: that was me troubleshooting trying anything I could think of, didn't realize it was the last saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo in line 29, it should be

```
markers: [],
```

Comment: So it renders, but I still get that original warning, any idea how to go about doing so? Thank you for your time though!

Comment: Why do you put markers' ref into a state variable? Just put it in ordinary variable like you did on carousel. If you call setState within render, it will cause infinite loop.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? ref={ref => this.markers[index] = ref}

Comment: Yes, and don't forget to define markers variable

Comment: I tried a couple things but no luck, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: revised code:

https://snack.expo.dev/@aazwar/map-index-reference

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct link? The code is my original code.

Comment: it's under my account. You can diff the code to find the difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241763/discussion-between-justin-priede-and-roel).

Comment: When I diff, it says they are identical. I moved us to a chat.